# Get Domain of IFrame?

Tags: php, javascript, html, url, iframe

Is it possible to get the current URL that an IFrame is set to if it's loading an outside page (say, Wikipedia)? I've seen a few people say that it is impossible if it is not on your own server, but the places I've found that were 4 years old.

If it is impossible, is there an easier way to display a page inside another page and still have access to the url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is impossible because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Trying to do that will result in an access denied message in a normal (i.e. "compliant") user agent.

I don't think there is an easy way to get around this, as this is one of the cornerstones of browser security.

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe what you are looking for?

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ifr').src = 'http://www.example.com'">click</a>
```

Comment: I think what Tomalak said is what's my problem. Bummer.

Comment: Yes, what he said is right. My point was that while you can't get the URL, you can still set it.